# Bitcode bundle could not be generated because 'PermissionScope.framework’ was built without full bitcode

Tags: ios, iphone, linker-errors, bitcode, swift3

I added this `PermissionScope.framework` in my project and tried to archive the project but it shows following error.

> bitcode bundle could not be generated because '**AppPath**/PermissionScope.framework/PermissionScope' was built without full bitcode. All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: **Contact the developer of PermissionScope** and ask for BitCode support. https://github.com/nickoneill/PermissionScope

Comment: If you can't get a bitcode version of that framework then you will need to disable bitcode for your project